# Not getting the data from web page with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dynamic

I'm trying to get a table from a dynamic webpage using selenium but it's giving me issues. This is the Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://draft.shgn.com/nfc/public/dp/788/grid' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

global_dynamicUrl = "https://draft.shgn.com/nfc/public/dp/788/grid"
driver.get(global_dynamicUrl)
table_area = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="result"]/table')
table_entries = table_area.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
print(len(table_entries))
driver.close()
```

But this produces a "NoSuchElementException" Error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element with an ID of "result" on the page so that's why your locator isn't working. There is only one TABLE tag on the page so you can simplify your code down to

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

global_dynamicUrl = "https://draft.shgn.com/nfc/public/dp/788/grid"
driver.get(global_dynamicUrl)
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table_entries = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table tr"))
print(len(table_entries))
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it looks like the parser doesn't find anything, as if selenium is not rendering the actual data in the table.

Comment: @CarlosMarcano You will need to add the appropriate wait because the TABLE doesn't exist when the page first loads. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: thanks! That did the trick, although I can't still parse the actual names inside each cell in the table, I'm sorry. Bear with me and my ignorance, please!

Answer (score 1):

From the URL you have provided, I don't see any web element in the DOM matching your `XPath` expression - `//*[@id="result"]/table`. So the reason for your `NoSuchElementException` is the incorrect `XPath` with which you are trying to get the desired element.

**Below code locates table's column headers:** (Returns one `tr`)

```
driver.find_element("xpath", '//table//thead//tr')
```

**Below code locates all other `tr` nodes of the table:** (Returns 30 `tr`)

```
table_entries = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr[@class='ng-scope']")
print(len(table_entries))
```

Answer (score -1):

Atleast i don't see the above-mentioned locator in website, you can try something similar like below.
[image]

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: Thanks, should I change the line to this?

table_area = driver.find_element("xpath", '.table tr')

Comment: Yes, you should add the relevant code to your answer. You can keep the screenshot as well, if you think it adds to the answer. In this particular case, I'm not sure it does. Also, `'.table tr'` is not an XPath, it's a CSS selector. Instead of using a string to indicate the locator type, e.g. "xpath", use the attribute instead, e.g. `By.XPATH`. See the docs for a list of attributes, https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html.